# Is it a valid $\lim_{x\to 2} (0\cdot x)$?

Tags: calculus

Just curious.

Is it a constant limit i.e $\lim_{x\to 2} (0\cdot x)=0$, since all values will equal to $0$ and tends to nothing. And it doesn't involve infinity, so cannot be indeterminate.

Comment: Use "0" instead of "o". You have $0*x=0$, so  you are just taking the limit $\lim_{x\to 2}0=0$.

Comment: Why would it be indeterminate? Even if it was $1*x$ and not $0*x$ the limit would be 2, if it was $3*x$ the limit would be 6, etc, and when it's $0*x$ the limit is 0, there's nothing special going on.

Comment: You are asking good questions. Please read @egreg's excellent answer to clarify your terminology and you will be all set

Answer (score 2):

Notwithstanding the standard terminology where “tends to” is used, you should think to this *only* in terms of the definition (and theorems derived thereon). Avoid wordings such as “tends to nothing”. A limit *is* a number (or $\infty$ or $-\infty$), or it doesn't exist. Functions don't “tend to”. The *form* of a limit can be “indeterminate”, which simply means you cannot just plug in a value to compute it.

A constant function always has a limit at every accumulation point of its domain. Indeed, if $f(x)=c$ for all $x$ in the stated domain $D$, given $\varepsilon>0$, we can take $\delta=1$ and, for $0<|x-c|<\delta$, $x\in D$, we certainly have $|f(x)-c|<\varepsilon$, because $|f(x)-c|=|c-c|=0$.

Instead of $\delta=1$, you can take your favorite positive number, it doesn't matter.

If the limit at $\infty$ or $-\infty$ makes sense for the particular domain $D$, then also these limits will be $c$.

Your case is $D=\mathbb{R}$ and $c=0$.

Answer (score 1):

The limit of a constant $c$ is trivially equal to that constant $c$.

$$
\lim_{x\to 2}(0\times x)=\lim_{x\to 2}0=0
$$

The use (or lack thereof) of infinity is irrelevant. Suppose $x\to\infty$ instead of $x\to 2$. The answer remains unchanged.

$$
\lim_{x\to \infty}(0\times x)=\lim_{x\to \infty}0=0
$$

You are correct in the sense that $\lim_{x\to 2}(0\times x)$ is a valid limit. You are incorrect in your reasoning because infinity has nothing to do with this particular limit's validity.